# Opening files from version 2.8 in 2.79

Tags: export, import

This is probably a silly question but I need some help. I opened a file that I've been working on for about a month in the new 2.8 version of Blender. However when I tried to reopen the file in version 2.79, the scene is completely empty. Here is where the problem lies for me, I accidentally saved over the original file save while in version 2.8 . Please help. Thanks!

Comment: this is quite normal, working with two unreleased versions (2.8 in particular is quite far from being released, and it will change a lot). Even opening 2.79 with 2.78 may result in incompatibilities, see https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79

Answer (score 4):

You can copy the polygons from 2.8 to 2.79. You will lose your node setup but at least you will get back your scene. This happened to me just now - I couldn't find any answers anywhere, so i figured it out myself. I thought of this because you can do the same in Maya too, so I thought: "must work with blender too".

Comment: copy paste works, although it'll lose some animations. But you can append animations.

Comment: It does not work for me, I get "no buffer to paste from" in b2.79. I am on macOS.

Answer (score 3):

Not a way to open a file, but the ability to transfer objects:

Just try Ctrl+C Copy to bufer operator on selected objects and then Paste by Ctrl+V in another instance of Blender. 
Works both sides with nodes and other prorerties.

[image]

[Youtube video tutorial](https://youtu.be/s13zhb5FP88)

Answer (score 2):

**Compatibility Warning**

From the [v2.79 Release Notes](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79)

> When using add-ons in Blender 2.79 that take advantage of the new data-block pointer properties, the resulting .blend files can't be opened in earlier versions of Blender. Attempting to open such .blend files in Blender 2.78c and earlier may crash.

Answer (score 2):

Blender 2.8 is very much under development. The download page states "Do not use in production nor save important files with it" for a reason. You'll probably need to recover your file from a backup like the xxx.blend1 file Blender creates before overwriting.

Answer (score 2):

I first exported my model from blender 2.80 in .fbx format then imported it in blender2.79 and it worked.

Comment: No need to export to some 3rd party format. Just append the object(s) from the 2.8 file into your 2.7 scene.

Comment: i had issues with materials with fbx, and wavefront. i had best results with Collade (dae) but YMMV.

Comment: notable pain point with collada, materials that used multiple textures, only the last-most texture is exported, be sure to unpack-all and rebuild all all your materials by hand :\ yeah thats painful.

Answer (score 0):

hey you can always append things from 2.8 to 2.79. 
the best way is to export your meshes as fbx then import in 2.79. then append all the materials from the 2.8 file. reassigning is a little work but not too much.

Comment: Exporting to FBX (or any other format) is not really recommended, you will lose more data that way, like modifiers and object properties.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, exporting the files or projects as .fbx and re-importing in blender 2.79 or earlier works...Haven't tried the copy buffer stuff tho' but will....

Comment: Exporting is not a workaround for opening native files, you will lose lots of data like scene settings, modifiers, materials among others

Comment: Since the Blender 2.8 is still in its beta phase... No one can categorically open .blend files made in 2.8 in 2.79 or earlier....

Comment: Maybe another workaround would be to copy to buffer I think.. Select all objects or the models in the scene then Ctrl+C , open 2.79 or earlier and paste....Maybe that should work for you...But for now, .blend files in 2.8 cant be opened in earlier versions....

Answer (score -4):

While every layer is selected press Alt+H...let me know if it helped!