# Blender 2.79 can't open after using 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine

The past few weeks I've been learning how to use Blender with 2.79, but today I thought I'd give 2.8 a try. However, 2.8 crashes a lot because my computer isn't the best so I went back to 2.79. Turns out, it won't open anymore. I tried uninstalling 2.8 and 2.79, downloading and installing 2.79 again but it still won't work. All it does is stay on an empty command screen.
Is there any known way to fix this?

Comment: You said "I tried uninstalling 2.8". How did you try to uninstall it?

Comment: Are you trying to open a file that was edited and saved in 2.8 and then trying to open it in 2.79? If so, then this is a possible duplicate of [this question.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82677/opening-files-from-version-2-8-in-2-79)

Comment: Since it was a ZIP file, I couldn't really uninstall 2.8 so I deleted everything surrounding Blender. Temp files as well.
I'm not trying to open a file that was edited and saved in 2.8 and then trying to open it in 2.79, I never even saved a file in 2.8 to begin with since it was crashing on me so much.

Comment: It's solved! I had an SD card in my computer, which for some reason messed with my whole computer. Took it out and Blender started working again. Thanks for the help!